# Java group by custom variable and return same object

Tags: java, java-stream, grouping

I want to count number of duplicate in my list by custom variable (myHash)

```
Map<PersonHash, Long> result = list.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity(), Collectors.counting()));
```

This will count duplicate by id which is value in hash and equals function. How I can count it by custom variable ? In my case it is `byte[] myHash`

my pojo:

```
public class PersonHash implements Serializable {
    
    private Long id;
    private byte[] myHash;    
    ....
}
```

Comment: By method reference (object::method)

Comment: An array doesn't have a proper equals and hash function, so you need to define some object around it to do that.

Comment: I think you have a small logical mistake. Imagine you have two `PersonHash` objects, lets say `personHash1` and `personHash2` with an id of 1 and 2 respectively and  having equal byte array `myHash`; Which one should appear in the result map and why? How do you want to count them?

Comment: @Eritrean it does not matter, for me it is same object even they have different ID

Comment: Assuming you want to group by the contents of the arrays, use `Map<ByteBuffer, Long> result = list.stream() .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(p -> ByteBuffer.wrap(p.getMyHash()), Collectors.counting()));`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You have to override the `equals` and `hashCode` function of your object. Then you can do this with `Function.identity()`. I have overrides those functions like below:

```
@Override
public boolean equals(Object o) {
    if (this == o) {
        return true;
    }
    if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) {
        return false;
    }
    PersonHash personHash = (PersonHash) o;
    return hashCompare(personHash) == 0;
}

@Override
public int hashCode() {
    return myHash.length;
}

public int hashCompare(PersonHash other) {
    int i = this.myHash.length - other.myHash.length;
    if (i != 0) {
        return i;
    }
    for (int j = 0; j < this.myHash.length; j++) {
        i = this.myHash[j] - other.myHash[j];
        if (i != 0) {
            return i;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

And now with the following code:

```
    PersonHash personHash1 = new PersonHash();
    personHash1.setId(1L);
    personHash1.setMyHash(new byte[]{1, 2, 3});
    PersonHash personHash1_2 = new PersonHash();
    personHash1_2.setId(3L);
    personHash1_2.setMyHash(new byte[]{1, 2, 3});
    PersonHash personHash2 = new PersonHash();
    personHash2.setId(2L);
    personHash2.setMyHash(new byte[]{4, 5, 6});
    List<PersonHash> list = new LinkedList<>();
    list.add(personHash1);
    list.add(personHash1_2);
    list.add(personHash2);

    Map<PersonHash, Long> result = list.stream()
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity(), Collectors.counting()));

    result.forEach((k, v) -> System.out.println(Arrays.toString(k.getMyHash()) + " " + v));
```

You will get the following output:

```
[4, 5, 6] 1
[1, 2, 3] 2
```

**PS:** Please write better `hashCode()` function, I just want to demonstrate.

**Edit :** As @WJS Commented we could override the `equals` method like this, and we don't need the `hashCompare` function anymore:

```
@Override
public boolean equals(Object o) {
    if (this == o) {
        return true;
    }
    if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) {
        return false;
    }
    return Arrays.equals(myHash,((PersonHash) ob).getHash());
}
```

Comment: thx, I thought there should be some parameter in streams but I need to change pojo to do it right

Comment: @hudi Your welcome. Please mark this as an answer if it answers your question.

Comment: You don't really  need a `hashCompare` method.  You can use `return Arrays.equals(hash,((PersonHash) ob).getHash());` in your equals method directly.

Comment: @WJS yes that would be better. I'll edit my answer and change the equals method.

Answer (score 0):

You can't group by `myHash` and get an instance of `PersonHash` as key, if `myHash` is not the identifier and part of `equals` and `hashCode`.

If `myHash` is not part of `equals` and `hashCode`,
add a getter for `myHash`

```
PersonHash {
   getMyHash() {...}
}
```

and use

```
Map<byte[], Long> result = list.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(PersonHash::getMyHash, Collectors.counting()));
```

Afterwards you can match the `list` with the `results` to find the objects with the given hash.

Or use

```
Map<byte[], List<PersonHash>> result = list.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(PersonHash::getMyHash));
```

to get the list of `PersonHash` with the same `myHash` value.

Comment: @Eritrean of course, you are right! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Another approach without changing your current pojo (changes to equals and hashcode might cause errors some where else) could be to sort your list by your `myHash` field, then you could use an atomic reference to build your map

```
List<PersonHash> list // your list

Comparator<PersonHash> byMyHash = (a,b) -> Arrays.compare(a.getMyHash(),b.getMyHash());
BiPredicate<PersonHash,PersonHash> pred = (a,b) -> Arrays.equals(a.getMyHash(),b.getMyHash());

list.sort(byMyHash);

AtomicReference<PersonHash> ai = new AtomicReference<>(list.get(0));

Map<PersonHash, Long> result = list.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(ph -> {
            if (pred.test(ph,ai.get())){
                return ai.get();
            }
            else {
                ai.set(ph);
                return ph;
            }
        } , Collectors.counting()));

System.out.println(result);
```